# drop float div to next line if too wide

Tags: css

I have a box with key-value pair information.. If the value box is too wide and meets the key box then the value box must drop down under the key box

https://jsfiddle.net/nwpems8w/

The value on the third line must drop down under the key box? How to do that?

```css
.box {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 150px;
}
.box_prop {
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
}
.box_key {
  float: left;
}
.box_value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key</div>
    <div class="box_value">value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key long</div>
    <div class="box_value">value long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key giga long</div>
    <div class="box_value">value giga long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you set text-align:right; to those. change it for third one.

Comment: the solution must be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float: right` on `.box-value` and set layout on parent.

```
.box_value {
    float: right;
}
```

```css
.box {
  background:#aaa;
  width:150px;
}

.box_prop {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box_key {
  float:left;
}

.box_value {
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key</div>
    <div class="box_value">value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key long</div>
    <div class="box_value">value long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key giga long</div>
    <div class="box_value">value giga long value giga longvalue giga long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @clarkk answer updated. I thought you want text on left when it drops

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Flexbox`, just use `flex-wrap: wrap` on `.box_prop`

```css
.box {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 150px;
}
.box_prop {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box_value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box_value {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key</div>
    <div class="box_value">value</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key long</div>
    <div class="box_value">value long</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box_prop">
    <div class="box_key">key giga long</div>
    <div class="box_value">value giga long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```